# Gravity form Multiple receiver with different message

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

There is already an option to send single notification to multiple recipients in gravity form. How can i send diifrent notifications to multiple receipents using gravity form. Please somebody help me, i'm stuck here. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new Notification here and set email and content as per you require 
https://prnt.sc/n5u2b5